# Rendering a shiny plot in vectorized graphics (.svg) instead of .png

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

ggplot2 is able to export plots in vector formats like SVG. Plots rendered in Shiny with plotOutput() are rendered in PNG format. Is it possible to render Shiny plots in SVG format?

Comment: Yes, take a look at https://rdrr.io/cran/dqshiny/src/R/dq_render_svg.R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to output ggplots in a Shiny app as vectors thanks to the package [ggiraph](https://davidgohel.github.io/ggiraph/articles/offcran/using_ggiraph.html), by David Gohel. The package also supports basic interactivity to ggplot2 plots, like tooltips, highlighting, and more.